# android native app configuration for facebook require activity or fragment

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to android so this might be a stupid question from my side.I had followed the facebook sdk configuration for android and try to login so upto that okay working fine for the  time being i had written the login code in the activity class but change in the requirement i had go for fragment and write the same code in the fragment now something i had missed out and the login is not working for debugging i had checked the session and session state both thing are false.So,now the question is for the facebook android native app configuration acitvity class name is require or the fragment class name.For the code just follow the getting started with facebook sdk.Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Are you talking about the dashboard configuration?

Comment: yes..in the place of Class Name:

Comment: The configuration for login doesn't actually require any class name (try it, you can delete the class name in the app config, and login won't change - it's only for deep links). It's more likely that when you switched from an Activity to a Fragment, you either missed setting the Fragment on the Session's OpenRequest (or LoginButton, if you're using that), or forgot to override the onActivityResult method, which causes the callback to get lost. Please post some code (even if you just copied the tutorials).